# Removing feeds from header using a function?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I want to remove the default RSS feed, which I can successfully do by adding this in functions.php file.

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
```

However, It is important for me to use this in a function instead of using directly. For that purpose, I'm trying following:

```
function remove_rss() { 
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
}
add_action('wp_head', 'remove_rss');
```

but that does not work. I think the reason is the wp_head loads after the feeds are loaded in the header. How can I make it load before the header adds the feeds? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use the function by itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove feeds from WordPress totally?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33072/how-to-remove-feeds-from-wordpress-totally)

Answer (score 2):

[Try this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47087/10691) instead:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse58023_wp_head', 1 );
function wpse58023_wp_head() {

    // Removes main feed link(s)
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );

    // Removes comments feed link
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

why don´t use [remove_theme_support()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_theme_support) with add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_setup_theme') ?

```
function my_setup_theme() { 
  remove_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_setup_theme')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) instead. According to the [list of hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), it runs before [`wp_head`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).