# Remove all RSS from wordpress site

Tags: categories, rss, feed

I have a site with copyright content and do not want any RSS on it! I cannot have the content distributed legally. Specifially all categories have a default /feed that can be added to the end of the URL. I just found google was indexing this feed, but more importantly anyone who knows wordpress structures can figure it out anyway.

Is there a way to remove RSS functionality across all categories (/feed)? I looked around the internet and there are older solutions for removing one category found here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-certain-categories-from-site-rss-feed

A more indepth question is how to completely remove all RSS.

This solution [How to remove feeds from WordPress totally?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33072/how-to-remove-feeds-from-wordpress-totally) is not very sound from a maintenance perspective as quoted "It's also super hackish and will probably break at some point in the future". Also I'm not sure how this would impact SEO to have an active link go to your homepage.

I would prefer that the links not exist versus doing a 302. Is this possible?

Is editing the .htaccess to redirect the best solution? This is what I had in mind but it seems messy.

Comment: Please always show your research when asking a question and search the site before doing so.

Comment: In code: What have you tried, what didn't work.

Comment: The problem is i am asking how i could stop RSS without redirecting. I don't know what the proper way is, and from the "hack" done in the source i don't know if there is a way. If i knew how to code a solution I would have already.

Comment: You can adjust the solution in the duplicate and just remove the redirect.

Comment: My understanding in the solution is that you create an empty feed url however, versus it just not existing? I.e via the empty array.

Comment: @toscho This is not a dupe but i see im going to have to close this and just suffer since no others in the community will have eyes on this question now that its marked as dupe. The solution offered is a self proclaimed hack, dated (there may be a better way to do this now), and creates a dead feed at the url versus making it not actually exist. Let me know I'll delete this myself.

Comment: If you don’t deliver content, the URL _does_ not exist.

Comment: @toscho How do i answer my own question if my solution is different?

Comment: Write an answer to the other question. For me it **is** the same problem.